# how to set a cookie in current tab once ive grabbed it from an iframe -- chrome extension -- chrome.cookies is unavailable

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, google-chrome-extension, content-script

pen (sry fiddler kept resetting my fiddle instead of saving): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWqmPr

in my local, i have gotten it setup where the iframe is successfully grabbing another sites cookie and displaying it as the iframes innerHTML basically. i have it set into a var = cookieVal; as well.

i was going to try a document.cookie = "...cookieVal" within the setMyCookie() function thats triggered by the chrome extension... but wouldnt that just set the cookie for actual extension's page and not the current tab that youre in?

i have seen messaging as a possible solution but i dont quite understand how to implement it here. so if that is a solution some direction there would be nice.

manifest permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "history",
    "tabs",
    "https://*.cars.com/",
    "https://www.cars.com/profile/global/user-summary/"
    "http://*/*"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Setting `document.cookie` in the content script will set the cookie on the page, not inside the extension. So if you are injecting `iframe` from the content script then you can also set the cookie in the same content script.
- In case you want to set a cookie from the popup/background script of your extension without using `chrome.cookies` API [inject a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) into the active tab (this will require `"permissions"` manifest.json key for the given url):

  ```
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: 'document.cookie = JSON.parse("' + JSON.stringify(cookie) + '")'
  });
  ```

Comment: awesome. as for designating it as host only and session cookies, what is the document.cookie equivalent of: chrome.cookies.set({"Name":"CookieName", "session":true, "hostOnly":true, "value":cookieVal});

Comment: I think it's `"CookieName=" + cookieVal;` because it'll be session-only and host-only by default, but consult the [`cookie` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) for details.